# I want to move a polygon using move method in graphics.py module. My question is, what is the reference of the move method in polygons?

Tags: python

Am using using graphics.py module by zelle. Am trying to move a polygon using move method to a new coordinate. Move method take "x"&"y" coordinates to move rhe object to this new location. My question is  what is the reference of this method?eg
Rectangle(Point(4,5),Point(10,15))
Rectangle.move(20,25)
Now this new coordinates moves the rectangle to the specified location..i was wondering will python draw the rectangle from (20,25) or will it draw a rectangle around a centre point which is (20,25l

Python moved my object to specified new coordinates but the object didn't fit in the window in the new location

Comment: Read the docs... The inputs aren't the destination but the delta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the docs:

"`move(dx,dy)` Moves the object dx units in the x direction and dy units in the y direction. If the object is currently drawn, the image is adjusted to the new position"

The inputs are the delta of the object

https://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/graphics/graphics.pdf